# Trigger not triggering

Tags: trigger

On updating the opportunity, the trigger should get triggered. But it fails. Below is the trigger code which calls a method in apex class if it is triggered.

```
trigger TotalOrder on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    Map<ID, Opportunity> opportunityMap = Trigger.newMap;
    System.debug('hello');
    OpportunityController.validateOrder(opportunityMap);
}
```

Even the System.debug is not working. Can anyone please suggest something?

Comment: What fails?  Do you get an error or is the code simply not executing?

Comment: Note that the debug *might* not be appearing because your debug logs are not detailed enough and/or truncating the debug message because the log is too big.

Answer (score 3):

Is the trigger set as "active"? Setting is on the edit page of the trigger
[image]

Comment: Yes the trigger is active and it doesn't even display the debug message. So this means the trigger is not triggered itself.. So please provide some solution.

Comment: @Vetriselvan The debug message *may not display* if your log is too long, or your log levels are too low (you're logging at the default level). You might try dialing up the log filters so they show less data, and log at the error level, such as `System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, ...)`